# Comparing different adb logs

Tags: android, logging, adb, android-debug, android-debugging

Does anyone know of any proper way to compare adb logs of different timestamp? I normally use Beyond compare text compare option. but that will show all the lines as different since the timestamp will be different. If I want to compare the workflow of any process for example, if want to see compare the difference in IMS registration and working flow from 2 different set of adb logs, what is the easiest way? Need Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am removing time stamps with the help of awk and then comparing logs with meld.

```
awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 5; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the log using a format that does not include the timestamp so you don't have to remove it.

For example:

```
adb logcat -v brief
```

See more options at https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#outputFormat